# Argument is not fully displayed in discord.js v12

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, args

My arg is not fully displayed. It sends only the first word. I don't know what to try. Here is my problem I want to fix: Input: [image] Output: [image]And here is a hastebin with my code: https://hastebin.com/okayobanuz.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code says `const comment = args[1];` which is only one word, you need to use `const comment = args.slice(1).join(" ");` to get full argument

Comment: Now I'm getting ep,5,Test,Reputation

Comment: My bad, try using this `const comment = args.slice(1).join(" ")` (Also I edited my answer)